# С чего начать реализацию протокола (RTP+control over UDP)?

Tags: c++, linux, rtp

Мне необходимо реализовать протокол связи с радиостанцией по совершенно новому протоколу (APCO25 DFSI, если это кому-то что-то говорит). У меня есть на него стандарт и два простых требования: по протоколу должен передаваться звук и команды управления. Естественно в линуксе нет встроенной поддержки этого протокола. Так вот, собственно, как это делается? С чего начинают? Нужно ли писать библиотеку? И даже когда библиотека будет написана, как будет передаваться звук? Не лучше ли сделать две библиотеки: одна для передачи звука, другая для данных. В общем, необходимо понять, как вообще начинаю делать поддержку того или иного протокола, HTTP например?

Comment: Библиотека нужна для чего-то вроде [этого](http://www.google.com/patents/US20140022993) ?

Comment: Ну конечно прикладной уровень.

Comment: Мне кажется Ваш вопрос не содержит некоторых существенных моментов. Кто будет пользователем (конечным и промежуточным, человек, приложение итп) этого протокола? Понимая это, можно будет ответить и на вопросы организации интерфейса. Ведь можно и составной драйвер написать, содержащих звуковое и TTY устройства.

Comment: Пользователем этого протокола будет другая программа, которая захватывает звук и отправляет его на радиостанцию для трансляции, и ещё она принимает звук с радиостанции и подаёт его на аудиовыход. Так что в принципе, можно ничего в библиотеку не выносить, а сделать монолитное приложение. Но это как-то слишком грубо.

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы реализовать свою библиотеку для реализации возможностей того или иного протокола данных, необходимо провести подготовительную работу.

Например, начать с прочтения, что такое [протокол передачи данных](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85). Затем взять какой-нибудь простой известный протокол того же уровня, например [RTP](http://cdo.bseu.by/library/ibs1/net_l/tcp_ip/net/rtp.htm). Посмотреть [исходные коды библиотеки](http://research.edm.uhasselt.be/~jori/page/index.php?n=CS.Jrtplib), реализующей этот протокол. Написать пример с использованием этой библиотеки, тесты с неким набором тестовых данных. После этого, на мой взгляд, можно приниматься за написание библиотеки, соответствующей требуемому протоколу.

Ответ на часть вопроса о разделении билиотек будет получен как только будут написаны какие-то примеры с использованием других библиотек.